# netbeans 7.3 start up on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java

I have installed net-beans 7.3 on my Ubuntu.
On start-up of net-beans, It says that **jdk is missing**, though I have installed openjdk7.

running *javac and java* commands on the terminal give appropriate results.

It asks to continue without jdk and then all modules are disabled. Only c++ and php are left to code with.
Can anyone help. I aim to develop a J2EE application.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open ${nb-install}/etc/netbeans.conf in an editor and then set netbeans_jdkhome to point to the JDK installation directory (Should be a directory referencing "jdk" in /usr/lib/jvm for Ubuntu.) Alternatively you can provide the JDK path using the --jdkhome command line option for Netbeans.